# Cross product vector property

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If $a$,$b$ and $c$ are non-coplanar vectors and $d$ is a unit vector, then find the value of

$$ \| (a \cdot d) ( b \times c) + (b \cdot d) (c \times a) + (c \cdot d) ( a \times b) \| $$

independent of d.

My approach
Let $ A= a \times  ((b \times c) \times d)$

$$\begin{aligned}
  A & = (a \cdot d) (b \times c) - ( a \cdot ( b \times c) ) d
\\ & = (a \cdot d) ( b \times c) - ([a\,b\,c]) (d)
\end{aligned}$$

After this step i am confused.

Comment: What does $ a\cdot(b \times c) = [a\,b\,c]$ represent?

Comment: @ja72 That's the scalar triple product: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ScalarTripleProduct.html

Answer (score 2):

Let $V=$ the expression inside the modulus signs.
First, using the BAC CAB rule, we can calculate $$\underline{d}\times\underline{V}$$

I don't wish to write it out in full, but it is easy to check that this is **zero**.

So $$\underline{V}=\lambda\underline{d}$$

However, writing $\Delta=\underline{a}\cdot(\underline{b}\times\underline{c})$, we have$$\underline{V}\cdot\underline{a}=(\underline{a}\cdot\underline{d})\Delta=\lambda(\underline{a}\cdot\underline{d})$$

So $\lambda=\Delta$ and then $$|\underline{V}|=\Delta=|\underline{a}\cdot(\underline{b}\times\underline{c})|$$